# Does the Predator eat human flesh?

Tags: predator, predator-series

In the 1987 [*Predator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predator_(film)) movie, does the alien creature eat human flesh? And if not, *what is he eating*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Being that the Predator's alien species name is [Yautja](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Yautja_(Predator))

There does not seem to be much on what they actually eat, in or out of universe. But they are said to eat ["roots of an earth plant"](https://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Yautja), but not human flesh.

> **Virtually nothing of the predators eating habits is revealed in the**
>   **films,** the City Hunter from the second predator film did covertly raid
>   a slaughterhouse for frozen beef.
>
> - (Alien vs. Predator: Prey) **C'ntlip is a fiery Yautja brew that fogged**
>     **mind and body with pleasure.**
> - (Predator: Homeworld) **The Yautja was**
>     **observed eating the roots of an earth plant**, it was speculated that he
>     was guided to the root either through instinct or scent.
> - (Predator: Strange Roux) The Yautja in this comic is seen skinning and eating
>     muskrats.

Comment: If the Predator is said to eat raw meat in *Predator 2*, I'd say there is in-universe evidence... ;)

Comment: Also, is "Yautja" the name in *Predator* or *Predator 2*? I always thought that name was from the comics and extended universe. Or is it mentioned that this is the name of the species in the official shooting scripts?

Answer (score 17):

We don't see the Predator (Yautja) eating anything in the films. All evidence from the EU points toward them being omnivourous but with an emphasis on eating *raw* meat and veg.

> **[Predator: Strange Roux](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Predator:_Strange_Roux)** - *Muskrat meat.*
>
> [image: Predator slicing open a muskrat and eating it]

and

> **[Predator: Homeworld](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Predator:_Homeworld)** - *Some sort of root.*
>
> [image: Predator eating a root out of the ground]

They also drink an (alcoholic?) intoxicating beverage called c'ntlip

> Unbidden came a memory. Of a time when he and his brother had sat
> drinking c'ntlip, the fiery brew that fogged mind and body with
> pleasure. Someday they would be Leaders, not only of ships but of
> other Leaders. Great would be their fame. Stories would be sung of
> their Hunts for a thousand years, each of them was certain.
>
> <sub><sup>[**AVP: Prey**](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Aliens_vs._Predator:_Prey)</sup></sub>

Comment: ... anyone else feel like the writers decided to sneak an obscenity in with the brew naming?

Comment: From Wikipedia's summary, *"Keyes and his team have set a trap in a nearby slaughterhouse where the Predator has been visiting to feed"*. While we don't see it eating anything, the characters from the movie believe it eats raw meat ;)

Comment: @AndresF. - Sure, but it might just have been enjoying the cold or using the meat as punchbags.

Answer (score 0):

In Predator 2 it looks like it uses a straw to suck out the brains of King Willie

Comment: The Predator used a suction device to help clean King Willie's skull, but there's no indication that he actually consumed his brain matter.